# Building libphp5.so for embedding in C/C++

Tags: php, c++, c, macos, linker

I've been trying to build and link libphp5.so using the --enable-embed configure option, on OSX. This doesn't complete successfully, failing primarily because of object files not being found during the linking stage.

There are reports that the --enable-embed option has been broken on OSX for a long time.

Has anybody had any success doing this, linking and embedding the Zend Engine functions into a C/C++ app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to do this after lots of failed attempts. Here is a configure string that will build the libphp5.a library on OSX for PHP 5.3.6:

```
./configure --enable-embed=static --disable-libxml --disable-dom --disable-simplexml --disable-xml --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter --without-pear --without-iconv
```

Then, when linking to C/C++ code, you need to add libresolv to prevent link errors relating to DNS functions in the Zend Engine. For example:

```
g++ -o yourapp src/main.o -Lpath/to/libs -lphp5 -lresolv
```

Hope this helps somebody one day :-)

Comment: The extensions that have been disabled such as XML and DOM can be re-enabled but may need some additional libraries linked etc. This is just the first build process that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use some like this:

```
CFLAGS='-m32 -m64' LDFLAGS='-m32 -m64' CPPFLAGS="-m32 -m64" ./configure  --prefix=/usr/local --disable-cli --enable-embed --build="build folder" --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv/
```

And enable cli later with phpize, this work with 5.2.10 and up.

Edit:
look here: http://forums.wxphp.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=42 it is my full resolution with makefile etc... for 5.4.17.